# Adding a Library Path to the Linker in .NET MAUI and Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, linker, maui

Is there a reason why there is no option to manually control the Linker in a MAUI project in VS2022? With Xamarin there have been the options to change linking settings for [Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/linker) and [iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/linker?tabs=windows). Now I can only find the option for iOS but no options for Android

[Screenshot of the Project Settings in Visual Studio. It only shows Linker settings for iOS and not for Android. In both cases there is no option to add a path manually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVm1r.png) I don't have enough reputation to post images directly

Is there a different approach, maybe a config or xml file where I can add the path to my library?

*(Context: I want to include a .so library to my app and it doesn't work. [I have asked a separate question for that problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75664868/11163152))*

Answer (score 0):

You can check this article about the [Xamarin.Android project migration to the Maui](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/android-projects?view=net-maui-7.0) you can find the Linker changed in Maui.

If the legacy AndroidLinkMode setting is used, both SdkOnly and Full will default to equivalent linker settings:

- `<PublishTrimmed> true </PublishTrimmed>`
- `<TrimMode> link </TrimMode>`

With AndroidLinkMode=SdkOnly only BCL and SDK assemblies marked with %(Trimmable) will be linked at the member level. AndroidLinkMode=Full will set %(TrimMode)=link on all .NET assemblies.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) Does the article describe a possibiliy to add a library path to the linker? I read the article, but I still don't really understand how I can do that...

Comment: I can not find the method to set the linker on android in maui document, but it has the migration from xamarin to the maui,so you can check the xamarin method as a reference.