# How to include a .so library into a .NET MAUI project with Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, .net, shared-libraries, maui, dllimport

I want to include a ".so"-library (C++, Android) to my app:

```
const string DllName = "libHelloWorld.so";
[DllImport(DllName, EntryPoint = "HelloWorld")]
internal static extern string getHelloWorld(LibraryFuncsSafeHandle ptr);
```

This always throws `System.DllNotFoundException: 'libHelloWorld.so'` regardless of where the .so-file is located and even if I use the complete path in `DllName`.
I tried using different locations for my .so library (e.g in `project/lib`, `project/Platforms/Android/lib`, `project/resources/lib`,...). There are a ton of different recommendations/"solutions" on stackoverflow and other sites, where the right location for libraries is, but none of them worked for me.

Some answers here and on other sites recommend adding the path to the linker configuration/settings, but at least for Android, the linker is not acessable in VS.

[I asked a separate question about the linker](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75663602/11163152), so my question here is whether there is an obvious error in my code or something different I might have overlooked.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I had to use the libserial.so to access serial ports. I had a lot of problems too. Finally, it worked by placing that file in lib/armeabi-v7a/libserial.so and setting the file as AndroidNativeLibrary in build action.
The directory armeabi-v7a needs to be according to the app architecture.